# awk script header: #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/awk -f?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

In an awk file, e.g example.awk, should the header be `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/awk -f`?

The reason for my question is that if I try this command in the console I receive the correct file.txt with "line of text":

```
 awk 'BEGIN {print "line of text"}' >> file.txt
```

but if i try execute the following file with ./example.awk:

```
#! /bin/awk -f
awk 'BEGIN {print "line of text"}' >> file.txt
```

it returns an error:

```
$ ./awk-usage.awk
awk: ./awk-usage.awk:3: awk 'BEGIN {print "line of text"}' >> file.txt
awk: ./awk-usage.awk:3:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

If I change the header to `#!/bin/bash` or  `#!/bin/sh` it works.

What is my error? What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you explicitly run the `awk` command, you should use `#!/bin/bash`. You can use `#!/bin/awk` if you remove the `awk` command and include only the `awk` program (e.g. `BEGIN {print "line of text"}`), but then you need to append to `file` using awk syntax (`print ... >> file`).

`awk -f` takes a file containing the awk script, so that is completely wrong here.

Comment: in this case i need an awk to making a search in a txt file. So if i understand correctly, i should remove all references of awk in file. The same occurs in a sed file?

Comment: one last question, it is possible convert this bash (works in sh file) to an awk file?
awk '/\<SEN\>|\<REC\>|\<RECO\>|\<email\>/' word.txt

Answer (score 2):

Your script is a shell script that happens to contains an awk command.

`#! /bin/sh` tells your shell to execute the file as a shell command with `/bin/sh` - and it is a shell command. If you replace that with `#! /bin/awk -f` then the file is executed with awk, basically the same as executing

```
/bin/awk -f awk 'BEGIN {print "line of text"}' >> file.txt
```